# How to debug rails app when error only occurs in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So my rails web app is hosted on Heroku and I am getting an H12 error from Heroku meaning that the request takes more than 30s to get executed. I development, the request takes also a very long time to fully run but finaly works. So I don't get any error in development mode.

I get a hint at what the problem is when I look at the logs:

```
SubscriptionOrder Load (19.4ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SubscriptionOrder Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 AND "subscription_orders"."running" = $3 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["running", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (4.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (user_id = 107 AND (status = '') IS NOT FALSE AND created_at >= '2018-09-17 10:00:38.559259')
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 AND "subscription_orders"."running" = $3 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["running", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (user_id = 107 AND (status = '') IS NOT FALSE AND created_at >= '2018-09-17 10:00:38')
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "free_meals" WHERE (used = 'f' AND user_id = 107)
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subscription Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 AND "subscription_orders"."running" = $3 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["running", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (user_id = 107 AND (status = '') IS NOT FALSE AND created_at >= '2018-09-17 10:00:38.559259')
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 AND "subscription_orders"."running" = $3 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["running", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (user_id = 107 AND (status = '') IS NOT FALSE AND created_at >= '2018-09-17 10:00:38')
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "free_meals" WHERE (used = 'f' AND user_id = 107)
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Subscription Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 AND "subscription_orders"."running" = $3 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $4  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["running", "t"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE SubscriptionOrder Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subscription_orders".* FROM "subscription_orders" WHERE "subscription_orders"."user_id" = $1 AND "subscription_orders"."state" = $2 ORDER BY "subscription_orders"."id" DESC LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 107], ["state", "paid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE (user_id = 107 AND (status = '') IS NOT FALSE AND created_at >= '2018-09-17 10:00:38.559259')
```

... and so on and so on. The SubscriptionOrder DB request runs like a 100 times.

The thing is, I have no clue on how to identify what file, what line of code, produces this. do you have any idea on how I could do this ? from theses logs, find where my code the does this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an [N+1](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html) issue. You are looping through every user, and displaying their subscription orders, but making an SQL query every time.

That means a lot of SQL queries, which causes high load time. Typically, it means you will have to tell Rails to load the joined model in a single SQL query instead of when you first call it. The [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method will let you do that.

Adding the [bullet gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bullet) to your app will help you discover those N+1 issues and fix them.

Comment: To add to what @Damein MATHIEU mentioned, if you want to reproduce the same in local, you can take a DB dump of the production and run the same request and see how it turns out.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna thank you for your help, this is interesting although I don't need to do so because the same problem also occur in local, the only difference with the production environment is that I get to TimeOut error in local.

Comment: @Damien MATHIEU does bullet stops to look for N+1 issues when it finds one ? because it only gives me one N+1 error (although there are probably more than one) and it shouldn't be the most time-consuming one in the request.

Comment: I don't think it does, no. Try fixing that N+1, and you'll see if there are others being reported.

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU thank you so much for your help. So I solved this issue but I do not get any N+1 error, albeit my page il still very slow to load. Does bullet has a look in helpers ? it might come from my helper methods.